# Using Sequelize CLI with the ESM package

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Is there a way to execute Sequelize migrations with the [ESM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/esm) package? It requires the `-r esm` command line argument to be passed, but I don't seem to find that in their docs

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and the way I got around it is by calling sequelize-cli from the node_modules folder.

In my package.json

```json
{
    "scripts": {
        "migrate": "node --require esm ./node_modules/.bin/sequelize-cli db:migrate"
    }
}
```

then if you run `npm run migrate` it should work with es6 imports.

Comment: Do you need to run that build script everytime before you run the `npm run migrate`?

Comment: @dmikester1 my apologies, I copied that over from an old project and forgot to change the name of the script. In this situation the `migrate` script is what I was referring to in the `build` script.